# What is the difference between "feudal" and "feudalistic"?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, suffixes, differences

They are both adjectives related to feudalism. But what is the difference between the two in actual usage.

Answer (score 3):

[Feudal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/feudal) also means, "Absurdly outdated or old-fashioned" while feudalistic refers exclusively to a feudal system of lords and serfdom

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to try to explain the difference.

*Feudal* refers to some well-known feudal system from historic times.

*Feudalistic* would describe something else, which the author feels is similar to an established historic instance of feudalism.

If you feel that a social system *amounts to* feudalism, then you could say that it is a *feudalistic* system.